# Use of finish() and intent FLAGS

Tags: android, android-intent, authentication, back-stack

currently I am working on the login system for my android app.

I have implemented a OTP verification process in a custom BroadCastReceiver. Once the otp is verified an intent is sent from the BroadCastReceiver as below.

```
    Intent c=new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), SignInActivity.class);
    if (msgs[0].getOriginatingAddress().equals("+919920678579")) {
        c.putExtra("code", "verified");
        c.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(c);
    } else {
        Log.d("message ", "error, not verified!!");
    }
```

Now this sends data back to signIn activity where I check for a non-null intent

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in);
        btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
        Intent i=getIntent();
        if (i.getStringExtra("code")!=null){
            if (i.getStringExtra("code").equals("verified")) {
                Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, "verified!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //SHOW SOME UI CHANGES
                 Intent intent=new Intent(SignInActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            }

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        String phoneNumber = "+919920678579";
        byte[] smsBody = "+919920678579".getBytes();
        // DO NOT CHANGE THIS. IDK WHY ITS NOT WORKING IF REFERENCED FROM INT AND TYPE CAST TO SHORT!!
        short port = 6734;
        smsManager.sendDataMessage(phoneNumber, null, port, smsBody, null, null);
        Log.d("sms ", "sent");
            }
        });

    }
```

and my Dispatch / Launcher activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (ParseUser.getCurrentUser() != null) {
        //TODO: check validity of finish(). Supposed to remove this from backstack
        // Start an intent for the logged in activity
        Log.d("User logged in as ", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());
        Intent mainIntent=(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
        mainIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        mainIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(mainIntent);
        finish();
    } else {
        // Start and intent for the logged out activity
        Log.d("User ", "sent to signUp");
        Intent signIntent=(new Intent(this, SignInActivity.class));
        signIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        signIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(signIntent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

The flow is User clicks on app --> Dispatch Activity (assuming first time user) --> SignInActivity --> Sms is sent and received by broadcastreceiver --> Sends information to signInActivity after veryfing OTP --> Users goes to MainActivity page. At no point I want the user to be able to hit back button and go to the previous activity. I have tried using Intent flags and finish().  BroadCastReceiver sends intent to SignInActivity and not MainActivity cause I want to show an animation/ TOAST which is why I have a code checking for the non-null Intent. But im able to go back to the activities which is very frustrating. Could someone help me out please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First**, I believe you are overriding the flags you set using `setFlags`. To set multiple flags, you can use `addFlags`, or set all flags at once:

Setting all flags at once:

```
mainIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Or:

```
mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

For the same effect. Note that `addFlags` returns the Intent object, so you can even chain the calls together:

```
mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

**Second**, did you try applying these flags to the intent you send in your SignInActivity's `onCreate` method?

Comment: lol. that was one very very stupid mistake by me. Thanks a lot. Do i need to use BOTH finish() and the flags at the same time? Or will using one suffice

Comment: If used right, you shouldn't need the explicit finish() call.